# Install tomcat 9 on ubuntu server 18.04.3

Tags: server, tomcat

I tried following this:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/

in the last part of the heading **Step3: Install Tomcat** when I run the command:

```
sudo useradd -r -m -U -d /opt/tomcat -s /bin/false tomcat
```

I get error:

```
chmod: cannot access '/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/*.sh': No such file or directory
```

what should I do? Or is there some simpler page out there?
I do want to learn. But it seems lot of sites use "fancy" commands and dont tell what they do. And then when something like this happens, a noob is lost. Im guessing I had to change to "tomcat" user somewhere along the line, but it doesnt say where and how. I found that one can change by using su - tomcat. But following the site... i cant say where the passwd is set if at all. So im in a weird position where I dont even know what passwd tomcat user now has :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the /opt/ directory to ensure that the tomcat folder is there? That error can indicate that there is no directory the command is referencing.

For example, it cannot change permission on a directory that does not exist.

Try this instead:

Create a new group for tomcat-

```
sudo groupadd tomcat
```

Now create a new user, in this case called `tomcat`. Make the user a member of the `tomcat` group. Make that users home directory `/opt/tomcat` and give it a shell of `/bin/false`

```
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
```

Source:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: whats with the -s /bin/false? manpage sayes -s option has to do with aming shell. Usually its /bin/bash right? Does this, erm, the user cant use a terminal because of that option?

Comment: I checked and apparently /bin/false makes it a "system level" user, thus a user Im not supposed to log into. Which makes me think, why would I do that, because now I have pretty much locked myself out of that directory (since sudoing in with my other user wont work either now), and how am I supposed to change stuff in the directory if need be? It all seems weird to me x). I went the easy way around and just installed tomcat in a directory of my usual user :)

Comment: @brat that can work, but it is usually not recommended. You shouldn't need to worry a lot about accessing the directories because I believe they are just for installation.